# c# Asynchronous TCP server blocking clients

Tags: c#, tcp

I have developed an asynchronous TCP server in c#. Code goes like this

```
m_mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
    SocketType.Stream,
    ProtocolType.Tcp);

IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, portno);

m_mainSocket.Blocking = false;

m_mainSocket.Bind(ipLocal);

m_mainSocket.Listen(5000);

m_mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
```

OnclienetConnect  is like this,

```
deviceSocket soc = new deviceSocket();
soc.bytecount = 0;
soc.socket = m_mainSocket.EndAccept(asyn);
m_mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);

m_workerSocket.Add(soc);              

WaitForData(m_workerSocket[m_workerSocket.Count - 1].socket);
```

It works fine for some time(up to 30-40 minutes). After that it starts blocking clients.
Can anybody tell what may be the problem with this?

Comment: is `WaitForData` async? or sync?

Comment: Way too little information in your question to answer. What does WaitForData() do? How many clients are currently connected when new clients can no longer connect? How many clients had previously been connected and then ended their session? Are you correctly performing a graceful shutdown when a client disconnects?

Comment: how can I find if the client is disconnected?

Comment: @PeterDuniho welcome! assuming you're the same Peter Duniho that I'm thinking of: great to see you again; looks like microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp finally dried up. If you're *not* the same Peter Duniho that I'm thinking of... oops!

Comment: @MarcGravell: there is only one. :) Nice to see you again too. I'm still not sure what to make of this SO site. But I guess it's pretty much all there is these days, for better or worse. Glad to see you and Jon and others keeping things going. :)

Answer (score 0):

If it works fine for some time, and then stops, my main guess would be you're opening new Client sockets  (need to look at your code to make sure), and not closing them when you're done.

Windows (quite reasonably) has a limit of the sockets that you can open on a given port. If your application opens new sockets over time, and doesn't close them, you can reach this limit at which point the server will stop accepting new connections. I have experienced similar issues in the past.

Here is an interesting article you can look at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod